# How can I show off training or online classes I am taking on Careers 2.0?

Tags: discussion, jobs

Careers has an Education section profile section, but it is geared towards more conventional degree-oriented education. After undergrad/grad school, I have participated in traditional classroom-style training on secure programming and I have started taking UC Berkeley's free online Software as a Service class. I think it is important for prospective companies to know what degrees I have so I want that to be front and center, but I also want to emphasize efforts taken to learn after graduation. For training or online non-degree-track classes, I think most of the fields under **Education** are applicable except **Degree or Specialty**. Is there a place on Careers to put this information? If not, can there be a place to input this information? With old institutions like MIT/Stanford offering online classes and new institutions like Khan Academy offering online learning, I think people using Careers will increasingly want a place to brag about taking these types of classes.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see why you can't use the existing education section for this. Put MIT/Stanford or Khan Academy as the University or Institution field and put something like "Independent Study" for the degree program.  I just tried out a few different combinations.  There don't seem to be any restrictions on the fields in that section, so you can leave some of them blank if they don't apply.